# Modifying the header format in Excel (Pandas output) after splitting files

Tags: python, excel, pandas, header, formatting

I have a problem with modyfing excel output using pandas. I've just started to learn Python so probably my code is far from optimal.

I need to divide excel report into many files (based on representative ID), so there will be few thousand files after filtering one report.

The thing is that pandas has some default export style and I need to format it (i.e. change column width and format header a little bit to make it look nicer).

Splitting files worked well and suprisingly I even applied column width after iterating through excel files in the working directory.

I  tried to use "worksheet.write" or "worksheet.set_column" but it returned an error.

Below please find my code, many thanks in advance for any suggestions:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment, Border, Side, Font, Color, colors
from openpyxl import Workbook
import os
from openpyexcel import load_workbook

# define excel file path

excel_file_path = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/python/test.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1',index=False)

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# inserting report code (used later in file name)

code = input('Please insert report code:')

writer.save()

# define variable to split files based on ID column

split_values = df['ID'].unique()

# splitting files

for value in split_values:
    df1 = df[df['ID'] == value]
    output_file_name = "Report_" + str(value) + "_" + str(code) + "_Example.xlsx"
    df1.to_excel(output_file_name, index=False)
    

# define header format

header_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': True,
    'text_wrap': True,
    'valign': 'top',
    'fg_color': '#D7E4BC',
    'border': 1})

# add some cell formats

cell_format = workbook.add_format()
cell_format.set_font_name('Bodoni MT Black')
cell_format.set_font_size(15)

# iterate through current working directory and select appropriate sheets

path_to_xls = os.getcwd() # or r'<path>'
for xls in os.listdir(path_to_xls):
   if xls.endswith(".xls") or xls.endswith(".xlsx"):
        f = load_workbook(filename=xls)
        sheet = f.active

    # change column width - it suprisingly worked

    sheet.column_dimensions['B'].width = 20  
    
     # tried different methods below but these don't work
        
    #sheet.set_column('C:C', None, cell_format)
    #sheet.write('A5', None, cell_format)

        #sheet.set_row(0, None, cell_format)
 #for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
        #sheet.write(0, col_num + 1, value, header_format)
    
    f.save(xls)
    f.close()


 print('Done')
```

Comment: _but it returned an error_ - Which one? Please provide the entire error/stacktrace and reformat your code (remove the `>`).

Comment: The error was "AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute write" or similiar (for instance "set_column" instead of "write".

 I have appropriate libriaries imported so I guess that maybe problem is connected with the "sheet" variable?